# Unable to execute exe file in saucelab

Tags: java, saucelabs, selenium-remotedriver

```
  I want to run .exe file on Saucelabs . I was  using maven dependency 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>saucerest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.35</version>
     </dependency>
  Code :-
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();    
            options.setCapability("platform", "Windows 10");
            options.setCapability("version", "81");
            options.setCapability("parent-tunnel", "companytest");
            options.setCapability("tunnelIdentifier", "Company-Stage");
            SauceREST api = new SauceREST(SAUCE_USERNAME, SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY);
            File prerunFile = new File("Drivers//test.exe");
            api.uploadFile(prerunFile);
            HashMap<String, String> prerunParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
            prerunParams.put("executable", "sauce-storage:test.exe");
            prerunParams.put("background", "true");
            options.setCapability("prerun", prerunParams);
       and Storage center was :-
           https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage
        But as per the company now saucelab has different storage center which is 
https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/v1/storage and maven dependency has been changed with new api.
      New Maven dependency :-
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>saucerest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
so new api has been introduced i.e
SauceREST api = new SauceREST(SAUCE_USERNAME, SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,DATACENTER.US_WEST);
here i'm not getting any api to upload the file in saucelab storage.
```

Answer (score 0):

SauceREST had breaking changes, see the README https://github.com/saucelabs/saucerest-java#saucerest-2x.  What exactly is your error?

FYI Storage API docs are located here: https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/api/storage/